# viewmodel dependencies not working in android studio

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, viewmodel, lifecycle

My dependencies are as follows

```
    // Lifecycle Components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.2"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.2"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.2"
```

It is showing the following error
Could not find androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-view-model:2.6.2.
Searched in the following locations:
[The link is showing not found on being opened](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-view-model/2.6.2/lifecycle-view-model-2.6.2.pom)
[Same as above](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-view-model/2.6.2/lifecycle-view-model-2.6.2.pom)
Also tried this but showing the same error and the link is not found
From google documentation

```
    dependencies{
         `   Val lifecycleVersion = "2.6.2"
           ` Val archVersion = "2.2.0"`
`
                `   // ViewModel
                    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycleVersion")
                    // LiveData
                    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycleVersion")
                    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
                    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycleVersion")

                     // Saved state module for ViewModel
                    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-saved-state:$lifecycleVersion")

        
                    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
                    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion")``
                }
```

```
    / Repository configuration
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error says "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-view-model:2.6.2" - you need to find where you've incorrectly written `view-model` instead of `viewmodel`.

Comment: I have changed view-model to viewmodel but when I open the app it crashes and I had not written any code until now which can cause that bug. And when  add ' implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.2")' it still crashing.